# How to set Focus to tizen web app document object for eventListener? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, document, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am developing a Tizen Webapp for Watches with bezel input.
To listen for the Bezel rotation event on the HTML document I used the following code:

```
rotaryDetentCallback = function rotaryDetentHandler(e) {
    var direction = e.detail.direction;
    if (direction === "CW") {
     alert("<-");
    } else if (direction === "CCW") {
     alert("->");
    }
}; 
document.addEventListener("rotarydetent", rotaryDetentCallback, false);
  console.log(document.hasFocus());//returns true

$('select').on('change', function(){
  console.log(document.hasFocus());  //Prints false
  document.activeElement.blur();     //doesnt work
  window.focus();                    //doesnt work
  document.focus();                  //retuns error
});
```

The `rotarydetent` listener works great but after I change any Select element in the App at runtime, the document loses focus and the event is not firing any more.

How can I get the focus back to `document` object after select change?

**PS:** the standard UI for Select Tag on Tizen wearable web-apps uses the bezel also, so I guess it takes the eventListener from document and doesn't give it back.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function `document.focus()` and `window.focus()` is for restoring the focus [to the current window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus) (*apparently if you have multiple ones open*) and not for bringing it back to the contents of the page.

Try to focus `document.body` or its focusable ancestor instead - the one being a **form field**, or a **link** or having an appropriate **`tabIndex` attribute**.